# Python how to trigger a code when something from another program happends

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to use `python3` to make a "chat bot", but, i don't want it to be complex, i just want it to say something when someone enters the chat room `imvu`. Any ideas where to get some docs to read or something? Would be nice. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend watching the YouTube channel called The Coding Train because he has done a few things with chat-bots and twitter-bots. If that's not what you're looking for do a few quick google searches on the subject "how to make a chat-bot" or something like that. there's a lot of material out there.

Comment: You cant read the memory of another executing program, without knowing the process Id, the offsets for the position in memory and the bit location. You would have to look into web hooks, events and sockets (also be the developer of both applications in this case). It also helps not to be rude to people attempting to help you.